# How to make ko.sortable work with ko.computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout and Ryan Niemeyers [ko.sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable).
My aim is to move items from one container to another. This works nice.
However, due to other circumstances I want the observableArrays object to be drag´n´dropped to be ko.computed.

I have a basic array containing all my elements

```
self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray();
```

then I have a filter version

```
self.TextsTypeOne = ko.computed(function(){
   return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Textbatches(),function(t){
       return t.type() === '1';
   });
});
```

I have another filtered list with the texts dragging:

```
self.allocationableTextbatches = ko.computed(function(){
   return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Textbatches(),function(t){
       return t.type() === null;
   });
});
```

Then I create my two containers with ´self.TextsTypeOne´ and  ´self.allocationableTextbatches´:

```
<div id="allocationable-texts" class="menupanel">
    <h4 class="select">Text(s) to allocate:</h4>
    <div class="tb-table">
        <div class="tb-list" data-bind="sortable:{template:'textbatchTmpl',data:$root.allocationableTextbatches,allowDrop:true}"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="TypeOne-texts" class="menupanel">
    <h4 class="select">Text(s) on scene:</h4>
    <div class="tb-table">
        <div class="tb-list" data-bind="sortable:{template:'textbatchTmpl',data:$root.TextsTypeOne,allowDrop:true}"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

where

```
<script id="textbatchTmpl" type="text/html"><div class="textbatch" data-bind="click: $root.selectedText">
    <span class="tb-title" data-bind="text: title"></span>
```

I can easily add buttons to my template setting type to 'null' and '1' respectively, and make it work that way. However I want this to be a drag and drop feature (as well) and the ko.sortable works on the jquery-ui objects. Thus it needs ´ordinary´ ´ko.observableArrays´ and not ´ko.computed´s as it is 'splice´-ing the observableArray, and dragging and dropping results in an error "TypeError: k.splice is not a function".

I have tried to make ´self.allocationableTextbatches´ and ´self.TextsTypeOne´ writable computed, but to no avail.

Any help and suggestions is highly appreciable!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but does it work if you use the internal array i.e. `$root.TextsTypeOne()` instead of just `$root.TextsTypeOne`?

Comment: Thankx, @DonovanM. I´ll experiment with that. I did managed to get rid of the splice-error by applying som unwrapping of variables in the ko.sortable. However I still need to update the 'type' of the underlying array. Guess I must apply some logic on target/source together with beforeMove- or afterMove-options, but the query-ui stuff is not my strong side...

Comment: You can always subscribe to `self.Textbatches` (something like `self.Textbatches.subscribe(function ...`) and make `TextsTypeOne` and `allocationableTextbatches` observableArrays. Then you can update them whenever `self.Textbatches` changes.

Comment: This is a good idea for allocationableTextbatches. However my problem here is that I work on TextTypeOne and any changes on that ui-wise needs to update on Textbatches (which again can update TextTypeOne and allocationableTextbatches). I need a back door in so to speak.